# Overflow-x: Hidden being overridden

Tags: javascript, css

I've been struggling to figure out why:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

isn't being applied to mobile only pages that I'm using these product widgets on:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.avantlink.com/product_ad_widget/paw.php?pawid=168457&amp;pw=302869&amp;output=js"></script>
```

Example page: [link](https://noahlangphotography.com/hawaii-hiking-pants-products)

I've been able to narrow the error down to the widgets from this provider only, but I can't understand why some simple CSS with the !important on there is being overridden.

Is there a simple way to always apply my styles over theres?

Thank you!